# Retrieve elements removed by List splice

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Is there a way to receive the elements that were excluded from a [`List`](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List) during a [`splice()`](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/splice) operation?  `splice()` seems to return a new `List` with the elements spliced excluded, which is what I expected according to the API, but I am not sure how to get the elements that I excluded.

```
const a: List<number> = List<number>([1, 2, 3, 4]),
    b: List<number> = List<number>(a.splice(1, 1));
console.log(a.toArray()); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(b.toArray()); // [1, 3, 4]

// How would I get the hypothetical [2] that was excluded?
```

I assumed that `splice()` would mirror the native [`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) or at least provide some way to get both the new `List` and the removed elements.

Do I have to break this into 2 steps using a [`slice()`](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/slice) and then a `splice()`?

```
const a: List<number> = List<number>([1, 2, 3, 4]),
    excluded: List<number> = List<number>(a.slice(1, 2)),
    b: List<number> = List<number>(a.splice(1, 1));
console.log(a.toArray()); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(b.toArray()); // [1, 3, 4]
console.log(excluded.toArray()); // [2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use slice method instead of splice.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: That's the JS native Array object.  I'm talking about immutable.js' List object.